# Issues with Kile live preview while running on windows

Tags: windows, kile

I recently downloaded Kile 2.1 via the KDEwin installer. The editor runs flawlessly, except for the live preview.

In the log and messages I get an error message saying:

> [Kile] Unknown tool LivePreviewPDFLaTeX.

I get this several times in a row, so I suppose Kile tries to run the live preview each time but does not find the tool.

I did a system check on Kile (`Settings` -> `System Check...`) and no critical failures were found, Okular is installed and working.

Anybody knows of this issue and has a possible solution?

Comment: I am having the same problem.
A solution will be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743153/issues-with-kile-live-preview-while-running-on-windows?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Thanks for this post,
I am having the exact same problem. Resetting the configuration did not change anything. Apparently the tool "LivePreviewPDFLaTeX" is not predefined in the standard settings
(It probably should be listed among all the other tools in -->settings-->configure-->tools-->build.) I tried to construct the tool myself, but this did not work so far. I will take a look in my kubuntu-based kile installation on my private computer tonight to see what the tool should look like. Heads up,
N

Answer (score 3):

As stated at the bottom of [this page](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/kile/index.php?title=Live_Preview), after the update of Kile and Okular,

> it is recommended to reset the configuration of the tools. In order to
>   do so,
>
> - open the tool configuration section in the configuration
>     dialog, which can be found under *Settings / Configure Kile... / Tools
>     / Build*, and
> - press the *Restore Default Tools...* button.

If this is not enough, check if your `kilerc` file is properly configured, as stated [here](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=107511). The steps are:

- restore the default tools using the wizard, as stated above,
- if needed, create manually the LivePreview tool, using the wizard in *Settings / Configure Kile... / Tools / Build*
- locate the `kilerc` file (which can be found in `%APPDATA%\.kde\share\config`)
- change the `[Tool/LivePreviewPDFLaTeX/Default]` section according to

this

```
[Tool/LivePreviewPDFLaTeX/Default]
autoRun=no
checkForRoot=no
class=LaTeXLivePreview
close=
command=pdflatex
jumpToFirstError=yes
menu=Compile
options=-synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory='%dir_target' '%source'
to=pdf
type=Process
```

Comment: I tried what's suggested here and various variations, and after two hours of trying to make it work, absolutely no change. I give up. I will just stick to refreshing manually.

Answer (score 2):

Hello I Think I had the same problem and i found the solutio. Just go to **Settings** > **Configure-Kile**. It opens a Configure-Kile window. On the left you will find **Kile** and expand it (if not expanded already) by clicking the **+** sign and you will see **Live Preview**, select it and then uncheck "Enable Live Preview"....and it should work fine....Enjoy kile on windows :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  How does this answer the question?  It seems to turn theses previews off.

Comment: works on debian 10 in same manner

Answer (score 1):

After such an update it is recommended to reset the configuration of the tools. In order to do so, open the tool configuration section in the configuration dialog, which can be found under Settings / Configure Kile... / Tools / Build, and press the "Restore Default Tools..." button.