# Kile KDE installation under window 7

Tags: installing, kile

I've encountered a problem very similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48430/issues-with-kile-live-preview-while-running-on-windows): I'm trying to run Kile 2.9.60 on windows through KDE 4.8.00. After successfully installing Kile with the dependent packages (Kile, Kate, kde-baseapps,kde-workspace,okular), I've managed to run it but I cannot compile PDF files. I get the following error:

> [Kile] Unknown tool LivePreviewPDFLaTeX.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Is there is a known solution, googling the phrase above did not yield anything interesting.

Comment: Kile offers a menu. Click "configure" and look out for "Tools", "Preview". Something strange there? Did you try to disable "Live Preview" in the settings?

Comment: Try this link, it should be of some use to you:
http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=107511&sid=1ab399604cdc41f7e98bf9239427b59a&start=15